# Asymptotic Expected Running Time

Tags: performance, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

I'm having some trouble with an asymptotic analysis question. The problem asks for both the asymptotic worst case running time and the asymptotic expected running time of a function. Random(n) generates a random number between 1 and n with uniform distribution (every integer between 1 and n is equally likely.)

```
Func2(A, n)
/* A is an array of integers */
1 s ← A[1];
2 k ← Random(n);
3 if (k < log2(n)) then
4    for i ← 1 to n do
5       j ← 1;
6       while (j < n) do
7          s ← s + A[i] ∗ A[j];
8          j ← 2 ∗ j;
9       end
10   end
11 end
12 return (s);
```

I was wondering how line 3 (if (k < log2(n)) then) effects the expected running time of the function. I believe lines 4 - 10 run at worst case cn^2 time, but I am unsure how to derive the expected running time due to the if statement. Thanks for any help!

-Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For big n, k almost always bigger then log(n). For example for n=1024, log(1024)=10
Probability that you will execute cycle is P=log(n)/n
So Time will be

```
(log(n)/n)*(n*log(n))+ O(RandomFunc(n))
```

So everything depend on  O(Random(n)). If O(Random(n)) = O(n)

```
O(n)>O(log(n)^2) = O(n)
```

Lines 4-10 is O(nlog(n))

Comment: j is increasing by a multiple of 2 every time. Would that not indicate that (while j < n) will execute log(n) times? And I believe we are to make the assumption that Random(n) runs in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

**A tip:**

The running time of lines 4-10 is not O(n^2).

Consider the values of j for the while loop:

j = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...

That's not O(n).

Comment: I apologize, lines 4-10 would run at nlog(n) time correct? The problem also asks for the Expected Running Time of the function given that Random(n) produces a random number between 1 and n with uniform distribution. Is it correct that,

ET(n) = Pr(k < log(n))ET(k < log(n)) + Pr(k > log(n))ET(k > log(n))

Comment: Yes, lines 4-10 would be worst case `n log n`. I haven't dealt a lot with expected running time, so your guess is probably better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma Notation, you can methodically do:

[image]